# How to set edit mask where zero means 0 and not any other number?

Tags: string-formatting, mask, powerbuilder

**Situation**: 
Character 0 has special meaning in number display formats. My code picks date on certain conditions and make display format for another edit field (column in DW) for example **1905** where **19** is last 2 digits of current year and **05** is the current month + "-" + "####" so final display format that i want to set becomes like **1905-####**.

**Problem**:
The zero in **1905** shows up in the target edit field (column) as **19 5**. There is space shown at the location where **0** resides. The final result of the edit mask **1905-####** shows in edit field as 1**9 5-** and cursor points exactly after digit **9** which i dont want.

**Expecting**:
I want to have the display format as "1905-    " and keyboard cursor pointing after dash '-' for remaining 4 digits entry.

**Question**:
How to set number display format or edit mask to ignore special meaning of **0** and take **0** as digit zero and not as any other number?

For example this is how i set mask for Trans_ID column which is string type column.

```
dw_1.Object.Trans_ID.EditMask.Mask = Right(String(Date(dw_1.Object.DOB[1]), "YYYY"),2) +  String(Date(dw_1.Object.DOB[1]), "MM") + "-####"
```

PowerBuilder v12.5

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string(month(today()), '00')
```

or, for the whole string

```
Right(String(Date(dw_1.Object.DOB[1]), "YYYY"),2) +  String(month(Date(dw_1.Object.DOB[1]), "00") + "-####"
```

Comment: no difference Marc. Please read the question again.  actually, edit mask when set to 0 the edit field (column) will show a space instead of 0. I need to tell PB that 0 edit mask is zero and has no special meanings. Thank you for any efforts.